# I have a question about permutation.

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations

I have the following question:

Determine the value of n from:

<sub>n</sub>P<sub>3</sub> = 5 (<sub>4</sub>P<sub>2</sub>)

I don't know how I should begin to tackle this problem? Any tips/help would be appreciated.

permutations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RHS is $(5)\cdot \frac{4!}{(4-2)!} = (5)(12) = 60$

The LHS is $\frac{n!}{(n-3)!} = n(n-1)(n-2)$. So you need the product of three consecutive natural numbers to be $60$. An easy guess would give you $n=5$.

OK, to be a little more systematic, three consecutive naturals would comprise either even, odd, even (case 1) or odd, even, odd (case 2). In the first case, one even would be a multiple of $4$ (since alternate evens are multiples of $4$), which would make the product a multiple of $8$. But $60$ isn't a multiple of $8$. So case 2 must hold, and the middle number has to be even. Furthermore, the middle even must be a multiple of $4$ as $60$ is a multiple of $4$. And so we try the *first* positive multiple of $4$, namely $4$ itself as the middle number to get $(3)(4)(5) = 60$ as required, and we're done.

You can, of course, expand and solve the cubic but that's just unnecessary here.